# How do I import XML data using Excel VBA?

Tags: xml, vba, excel, msxml

I'm trying to import data from an XML file like this:

```
<library>
<book>
<title>aaa</title>
<author>aaa-author</author>
</book>
<book>
<title>bbb</title>
<author>bbb-author</author>
</book>
<book>
<title>ccc</title>
</book>
</library>
```

(note that the third book has no value for the author)

I would like to obtain an Excel table where each book's data are displayed on one row. The problem is that I do not understand how I have to loop on the book nodes to obtain their children values.

I'm working on code like this:

```
Set mainWorkBook = ActiveWorkbook
Set oXMLFile = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
XMLFileName = "C:\example.xml"
oXMLFile.Load (XMLFileName)
Set Books = oXMLFile.SelectNodes("/book")
For i = 0 To (Books.Length - 1)
   ' I cannot understand this part
Next
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add a reference (**Tools -> References ...**) to **Microsoft XML 6.0**. This will allow you to have typed variables (`Dim book As IXMLDOMNode`), which will give you Intellisense.

Then you can use the following code, which iterates through all the `book` elements, saves the `title` and `author` into a 2-dimensional array (if they are available), then pastes the array into an Excel worksheet:

```
Dim oXMLFile As New DOMDocument60
Dim books As IXMLDOMNodeList
Dim results() As String
Dim i As Integer, booksUBound As Integer
Dim book As IXMLDOMNode, title As IXMLDOMNode, author As IXMLDOMNode

'Load XML from the file
oXMLFile.Load "C:\example.xml"

'Get a list of book elements
Set books = oXMLFile.SelectNodes("/library/book")
booksUBound = books.Length - 1

'Create a two-dimensional array to hold the results
ReDim results(booksUBound, 1)

'Iterate through all the book elements, putting the title and author into the array, when available
For i = 0 To booksUBound
    Set book = books(i) 'A For Each loop would do this automatically, but we need the
                        'index to put the values in the right place in the array
    Set title = book.SelectSingleNode("title")
    If Not title Is Nothing Then results(i, 0) = title.Text
    Set author = book.SelectSingleNode("author")
    If Not author Is Nothing Then results(i, 1) = author.Text
Next

'Paste the results into the worksheet
Dim wks As Worksheet
Set wks = ActiveSheet
wks.Range(wks.Cells(1, 1), wks.Cells(books.Length, 2)) = results
```

Links:

- [A Beginner's Guide to the XML DOM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa468547.aspx)
- [Query XML Files Using VBScript](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2008.10.heyscriptingguy.aspx)
- [Progarm the DOM with Visual Basic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms766564(v=vs.85).aspx) - contains a number of nice walkthroughs

References:

- XML DOM - [Concepts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms764620(v=vs.85).aspx), [Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms764730(v=vs.85).aspx)

  - [selectNodes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754523(v=vs.85).aspx)
  - [selectSingleNode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms757846(v=vs.85).aspx)
- VBA - [Dim statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa243352(v=vs.60).aspx)
- Excel - [Range property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff834676.aspx), [Cells property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196273.aspx)